# MongoDB Group by Key PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

Ok, so I have a collection in my MongoDB

here is a sample my key here is

> company

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4fdfe7b536314b4147000000"),
   "company": "hoyts",
   "barcode": "236602253",
   "name": "Gold Class",
   "logoURL": "http: \/\/www.incard.com.au\/newsite\/template\/images\/movieticket\/4cinemas\/ticketpic1.png",
   "store_name": "movies" 
}
```

Now the issue here is I have 4 rows/collects with hoyts, I need away to group them.

my current code

```
public function getstore($storename)
    {
        // select a collection (analogous to a relational database's table)
         $collection = $this->db->products;

        // find everything in the collection
        $cursor = $collection->find(array("store_name"=>$storename));

        $test = array();
            // iterate through the results
            while( $cursor->hasNext() ) {
                $test[] = ($cursor->getNext());
            }
        //Print Results 
        print json_encode($test);

    }
```

I tried using

> group($key)->find

however that did not work.

Could someone give me a hand thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this example: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.group.php